# extjs grid cell editing, row vanishes after leaving cell

Tags: json, extjs, grid, row, listener

I got a grid with a listener function in that ensures, that only certain cells (every second row in a block of 3 rows) will be edited. But after leaving the cell, all values in the row changed! I use a nested entry to store this "editable"-flag and min-max values. Those values remain.

Furthermore: The data (after editing a cell) is overwritten by data of the row above. And the last row in the grid gets the data of the first row in the grid.

Is it necessary to write back in a particular way?

I use JSON to store data in the grid, data coming from ajax und should be saved back same way later.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: need to show some code here for any hope of an aswer

Answer (score 0):

got it on my own! autoSync in the store was set on true...
Throughout this, every editing was disorderd
with this autosync ajax request